# android - Open BottomSheet and close keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I have an `EditText` in my `Activity` and `Button` to open `BottomSheet`. But if `EditText` had focus I need to hide keyboard first. I'm using this code to do it:

```
fun hideSoftKeyboard(context: Context, view: View? = null) {
   try {
       val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
       val focusedView = view ?: (context as? Activity)?.currentFocus
       inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(focusedView?.windowToken, 0)
   } catch (e: NullPointerException) {
       LogUtils.w("KeyBoard", "NPE in input method service")
   }
}
```

This is a code from my Activity:

```
class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var bsb: BottomSheetBehavior<*>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)

        bsb = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet)
        bsb?.skipCollapsed = true
        bsb?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN

        btn_open.setOnClickListener {
            hideSoftKeyboard(this, et_text)
            bsb?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }
}
```

But I have a huge problem with some keyboards. For example, when I use Samsung default keyboard:
https://i.imgur.com/k0DoFQG.mp4

As you can see keyboard doesn't have enough time to close and `BottomSheet` is already on its `STATE_EXPANDED`.

When I switch to Gboard, everything works as intended.

Comment: do it with if else on button click check if keyboard hide then open bottom sheet and in edittext check if bottom sheet dialog hide then open keyboard

Comment: @UsamaAltaf are you suggesting to force user press button twice to open bottomsheet? :) No, this is not a good option.

Comment: But you are doing both action on button anything will be happened first keyboard will hide first or BottomSheet will open first you need to it with different way like keyboard hides then open bottom sheet

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and my solution is the following:

```
 binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(binding.edittext)
            uiScope.launch {
                KeyboardUtils.hideSoftKeyboard(activity)
                delay(100)
                bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
        }

 fun hideSoftKeyboard(activity: Activity?) {
        activity?.let {
            val imm = activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.let {
                val currentFocus = activity.currentFocus
                currentFocus?.let {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So far, it works; however, I would definitely like to come up with a better solution since, at this moment, I have a delay.

Comment: @Adrian, thank you for the corrections.